# How to send Call back when an error occurred on request object in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, http

I have a situation where I'm catching error on request object using

```
request.on('error', function (e) {
            console.log("error while sending request: " + e);
          });
```

But I'm confused on how to send this error to client where i have to display the error. I'm only able to send errors on response object using `res.send();` any help is appreciated. I'm not using express.

Comment: Is this "catch error on request object" happens in Node.js web server? I checked https://nodejs.org/api/http.html document but no "error" event is found for request object.

Comment: @shaochuancs search for http.request(options[, callback])#
 and you can find it or try searching for .on('error'

Comment: It seems you are using Node.js as HTTP client, not server. Then what does "send this error to client" mean? The error is catched in client side...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return error on response object, to browser. You can use code like below:

```
const http = require('http');

let server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  res.statusCode = 403;
  res.statusMessage = 'Forbidden';
  res.write(JSON.stringify({message: 'something bad happens'}));
  res.end();
});

server.listen(3000, function() { console.log("Server Listening on http://localhost:3000/"); });
```